# Massless tadpoles vanish in Baikov representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-regularization

In dim-reg, massless tadpoles vanish. 
Is it the case also if we use [Baikov representation](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Baikov+representation) of the Feynman integral?

Comment: My two cents as a pedestrian: from the paper 1712.03760 it seems that in the Baikov representation you are still regularizing all of the Feynman integrals using dim reg, but then you organize all of these integrals to form some kind of system of DEs. I could be wrong, but as far as I can tell the integrals are still the ordinary dim reg'd objects, so I think the massless tadpoles would still vanish